# In PHP which loop should I use to have nested unordered lists?

Tags: php, loops

I have the following piece of HTML in a PHP app with an array including Group and Items. First I want to sort them by Groups, then within Groups have Items separated by comma (Item1, Item2, Item3), without ending comma.

```
<dl>
    <?php $groupname = '' ?>
    <?php foreach ($product['product_filters'] as $product_filter) { ?>
        <?php if ($groupname != $product_filter['group']) { ?>
            <?php $groupname = $product_filter['group']; ?>
            <?php echo '<dd>' . $product_filter['group'] . '</dd>'; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <dt>
            <?php echo $product_filter['name']; ?>
        </dt>
    <?php } ?>
</dl>
```

I want to have a the following result, but I don't know how to manage it and which loop should I use:

```
Group 1
    G1_Item_1, G1_Item_2
Group 2
    G2_Item_1, G2_Item_2, G2_Item_3
```

Comment: how your data look like? btw you can get separed items by fnc implode(",", $array);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two loops: one to restructure your data into groups, and one just for outputting it in the desired format. Note that you used `<dt>` and `<dd>` in the opposite sense: the groups are the titles, so use `<dt>` for them.

Also, your code becomes much more readable if you don't open and close the `php` tag on every line. Try to make code blocks that don't have such interruption: it will make it so more readable.

Here is the suggested code:

```
<?php
// Create a new structure ($groups): one entry per group, keyed by group name 
// with as value the array of names:
foreach ($product['product_filters'] as $product_filter) {
    $groups[$product_filter['group']][] = $product_filter['name'];
}
// Sort it by group name (the key)
ksort($groups);
// Print the new structure, using implode to comma-separate the names
foreach ($groups as $group => $names) {
    echo "<dt>$group</dt><dd>" . implode(', ', $names) . "</dd>";
}
?>
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/574172).